# VHDL integer'image(some_int) results in "Expression is not constant" error

Tags: vhdl

What is the correct way to convert an always changing integer variable to a string (to be displayed on a VGA monitor)? I have a series of if statements that take care of padding (so that the resulting string is always a certain length but as soon as I change:

```
resulting_string <= integer'image(87465);
```

to:

```
resulting_string <= integer'image(some_int_var);
```

I get an "Expression is not constant" error. What is the correct way to convert an always changing integer variable (that could be any int within the integer limits) to a string?

edit: not duplicate of the other question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer to String goes wrong in Synthesis (Width Mismatch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667051/integer-to-string-goes-wrong-in-synthesis-width-mismatch)

Comment: No, he has a width mismatch problem, which I have already solved. My problem is more advanced and more difficult to solve.

Comment: Please post the declaration of `resulting_string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went at it from every direction and finally found that I had to make a giant case block to get it to work. Now I can finally display rapidly changing variables that are really helpful for debugging. It's unfortunate that the solution had to be so retarded though..

(I already have a ROM for displaying text that the resulting string is sent to.)

```
function int_to_str(int : integer) return string is
    variable a : natural := 0;
    variable r : string(1 to 11);

begin
    a := abs (int);

    case a is
        when 0    => r := "0          ";
        when 1    => r := "1          ";
        when 2    => r := "2          ";
        when 3    => r := "3          ";
        .
        .
        .
        when 1000 => r := "1000       ";

        when others => r := "???????????";
    end case;

    if (int < 0) then
        r := '-' & r(1 to 10);
    end if;

    return r;
end int_to_str;
```

Answer (score 1):

`'image (..)` does not work on signals.

I think you are still missing the main problem: A monitor can not display strings or chars!

You need to implement
 1. a graphic buffer,
 2. a buffer reader that outputs VGA data.

Then you need to implement a manipulator to

- draw shapes
- clear the screen
- move areas and
- copy pictures into the buffer.

The glyphs are stored in a ROM and are choosen by a BCD value for each digit.

Converting an integer to a 'string' does not need a ASCII string, because the result is a BCD code (not ASCII). So you need to implement an (un)signed to BCD converter, too.

Comment: I actually was able to get it to work but I had to go full retard and make a giant case block such that every integer was represented by a specific string. i.e.: case int_input is .... when 254  => result := "254        "; ... I already have a rom that I use to draw text on the screen.

Comment: You just need ROM entries for every digit not for every number.

Comment: I already have that. This is an additional problem on top of that.