# to_string() alternative for VHDL 2002

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I need a function that will convert a signal (number) to string, in order to be able to display it on LCD. Unfortunately, I have to use Xilinx ISE 14.7 because Spartan 6 is not supported in Vivado, which does not support VHDL 2008.

Is there any alternative for `to_string()` function in VHDL 2002, or I have to implement my own function?

I can't use `integer'image()` on signals. For example:

```
signal counter : integer := 0;
integer'image(counter);
```

produces a compilation error: "Expression is not constant". I know there are a lot of options, for instance, converting the integer to BCD representation. I just want to know is there a simple and elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: You can write a normal VHDL function to transform the input data to a new output data. You can find an implementation in the [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) in package [utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/release/src/common/strings.vhdl?ts=2#L413).

Comment: If the signals have type `integer`, of course you can use`integer'image` (at least in VHDL. I suppose it's possible that ISE doesn't support enough VHDL for that, though.)

Comment: Vivado does support vhdl 2008. Just not all of it.

Comment: It's not hard to implement `function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length); alias input_str: std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp; begin for i in input_str'range loop image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i))); end loop; return image_str; end function;` IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.3.2.4 Predefined operations on array types, 5.7 String representations. Or do you have specific types and representations in mind?

Comment: You can use `integer'image()` on signals. You can't use `image()` on non-scalar types (arrays, records).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. If I use `integer'image()` on a signal I get a compilation error: "Expression is not constant", even with the function proposed by @user1155120

Comment: @JHBonarius It seems that Xilinx is really trying to make you use Altera products. ISE 14.7 is not supported on Windows 8/10, and it doesn't support VHDL 2008. On the other hand, Vivado doesn't support Spartan 6 chips, which were released in 2009!

Comment: See [Integer to String goes wrong in Synthesis (Width Mismatch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667051/integer-to-string-goes-wrong-in-synthesis-width-mismatch/20670059).  'image(x) doesn't return a value with fixed length for non-static values. to_signed/unsigned [integer return signed/unsigned] can work with static subtype parameters, they're in synthesis libs. Without to_string in a synthesis lib synthesis doesn't know the length relationship. A to_string would have to have a parameter with a static subtype indication and a static subtype as the return type mark to work. Doable.

Comment: @MarkoGulin 2009 is **8** years ago man! In that time I changed jobs 3 times, moved 2 times, changed girlfriend 4 times, married the last and we got a child together. You can switch to the Spartan-7 nowadays.